# RoR 3 has_many/belongs_to or has_and_belongs_to_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables in a Rails app that I'm using to track performance - Scenarios and Notes.  Scenarios represent a point in time and contain various other information.  Notes contain some information about the *differences* between two Scenarios.  What's a good way to set up my table schema so that it's easy to access a Note given two Scenarios?  Originally I set up scaffolding for the Notes like so:

```
rails generate scaffold Note scenarios_a:references scenarios_b:references data:text
```

This presents a couple problems.  The first problem is that it's a little unwieldy to search for notes given two scenarios.  The other problem I'm seeing now is when trying to display notes, I get this error:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Note::ScenarioA):
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

app/models/note.rb

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :scenarios
end
```

app/models/scenario.rb

```
class Scenario < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :notes
end
```

Accessing a note's scenarios:

```
  @note.scenarios
```

Accessing a scenario's note:

```
 @scenario.note
```

Comment: A set of scenarios can also have many notes, but is it really correct to make this a many-many relationship?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a join table.